# What happens when a ZooKeeper follower is dropped?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

In many ZooKeeper guides the following statement is made when discussing the syncLimit option:

> If followers fall too far behind a leader, they will be dropped.

What does "dropped" mean? I gather the connection is closed, but is the follower allowed to reconnect and sync?

Answer (score 2):

When a follower is dropped, it means the connection is closed and the leader stops pushing updates to it. Since the connection is closed, the follower eventually timeouts because it doesn't receive heartbeats from the leader and needs to look for a new leader. The election algorithm basically has all participants exchange the latest zxid it knows and whoever has the latest one is the leader. But if we assume there is a leader that has quorum of followers support when this follower recovers. The follower can just broadcast a message and ask who is the current leader that majority of other nodes are following and follows the same leader. The follower can then sync up to the leader.